# Apache Flume - send only new file contents

Tags: apache, server, virtual-machine, flume, flume-ng

I am a very new user to Flume, please treat me as an absolute noob. I am having a minor issue configuring Flume for a particular use case and was hoping you could assist. Note that I am not using HDFS, which is why this question is different from others you may have seen on forums.

I have two Virtual Machines (VMs) connected to each other through an internal network on Oracle Virtual Box. My goal is to have one VM watch a particular directory that will only ever have one file in it. When the file is changed, I wish for Flume to only send only the new lines/data. I want the other VM to receive this data and update/concatenate the data to a single file in a particular directory on it.

So far, I have this process very close to working. Whenever changes are made in VM1, they are updated on VM2. However, the entire file on VM1 is sent to VM2 every time, not the new lines. For example, if I wrote “Test1” and then a while later underneath wrote “Test2” to the file on VM1, on VM2 the output would be:

Test1

Test1

Test2

What I want to see is:

```
            Test1

            Test2
```

I am not sure how to implement this, and am sending this email after thoroughly examining the Flume user guide documentation and most relevant articles on stackoverflow/stackexchange. For your reference, below are the current configurations(they are working in the manner I mentioned above).

[VM1 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0FQ1.png)

[VM2 configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3rDq.png)

I realize another solution would be to keep the configuration on VM1 and overwrite the file on VM2 everytime new contents are detected. However, I am also unsure how to implement this.

Any assistance you could provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please ignore some of the comments in my code, I was trying things out. Forgot that was in there :)

Comment: I am now thinking, I could also solve this problem by having something delete files in the final directory periodically.

Comment: As another possible workaround to this I am thinking of attaching the destination directory to an agent with a spooling directory source and a file_roll sink, with the destination of the file_roll being the same directory. In this way I will essentially be doing a refresh operation, as the spooling directory source allows you to delete files after reading them in to the channel.

Comment: I am not sure, but [TAILDIR](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#taildir-source) source may fit better for this use-case

Comment: @gorros do you have any insight on what I have listed below? I am unfortunately running short on time and could use all the help possible? In short, using taildir source but the entire file is still being sent whenever a line is appended. I just want the single line to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Use TailDir source provided in Flume.It periodically writes last position read in position file and its more reliable than exec source as even in case of agent crashes or stops for some reason it will start reading from last position saved in the position file.

```
agent1.sources.src1.type = TAILDIR 
agent1.sources.src1.channels = ch1 
agent1.sources.src1.filegroups =f1
agent1.sources.src1.filegroups.f1= //path to log file 
agent1.sources.src1.maxBackoffSleep = 10000
```

Set maxBackoffSleep value as per your need it means how much max time agent should wait before polling for changes in log file , when it didnt find any changes in last attempt made.

Comment: I haven't checked this thread in a while since the project was delayed. I am about to try this out now. Will this only work for .json format? What if I wanted to transmit .txt or .csv?

Comment: So it does work for .txt format. However, it is still sending everything in the file everytime I just add a single line to the file. Did I misunderstand? So on VM1 I have a TAILDIR source and avro sink. On VM2 I have an avro source and a file_roll sink.

Comment: Please check whether position is being  written in file or not  ~/.flume/taildir_position.json

Comment: There is not .json file being created, or available in any flume directory. If it helps, these are my configs:

Comment: agent.sources=r1
agent.channels=k1
agent.sinks=c1

agent.channels.k1.type=memory
agent.channels.k1.capacity=1000
agent.channels.k1.transactionCapacity=100
#connect source, channel,sink
agent.sources.r1.channels=k1
agent.sinks.c1.channel=k1

agent.sources.r1.type=TAILDIR
agent.sources.r1.channels=k1
agent.sources.r1.filegroups=f1
agent.sources.r1.filegroups.f1=/tail_test_dir/test.txt
agent.sources.r1.maxBackoffSleep=1000

agent.sinks.c1.type=avro
agent.sinks.c1.hostname=10.10.10.4
agent.sinks.c1.port=4545

Comment: we can give custom position file location as agent.sources.r1.positionFile = /var/log/flume/taildir_position.json

Comment: So when I look at the file it gives: [{"inode":199647,"pos":4,"file":"/home/preston/Documents/tail_test_dir/test.txt"}]

Comment: I am still having the issue where the entire document is sent when a new line is added though. Does this give any hints?

Comment: TailDir starts reading from first line only when there is no position file specified. Last thing i can tell is change the interval time for writing in position file with property writePosInterval = 100 .May be you write new line in log before source logs position .

Comment: For reference of future readers, this did not work. My team is now looking into other alternatives as we are unaware if this is a possible Flume configuration to solve this.