# How to use the taildir source in Flume to append only newest lines of a .txt file?

Tags: apache, flume, tail, flume-ng

I recently asked the question [Apache Flume - send only new file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445343/apache-flume-send-only-new-file-contents)

I am rephrasing the question in order to learn more and provide more benefitto future users of Flume.

Setup: Two servers, one with a .txt file that gets lines appended to it regularly.

Goal: Use flume TAILDIR source to append the most recently written line to a file on the other server.

Issue: Whenever the source file has a new line of data added, the current configuration appends everything in  file on server 1 to the file in server 2. This results in duplicate lines in file 2 and does not properly recreate the file from server 1.

Configuration on server 1:

```
    #configure the agent
    agent.sources=r1
    agent.channels=k1
    agent.sinks=c1

    #using memort channel to hold upto 1000 events
    agent.channels.k1.type=memory
    agent.channels.k1.capacity=1000
    agent.channels.k1.transactionCapacity=100

    #connect source, channel,sink
    agent.sources.r1.channels=k1
    agent.sinks.c1.channel=k1

    #define source
    agent.sources.r1.type=TAILDIR
    agent.sources.r1.channels=k1
    agent.sources.r1.filegroups=f1

    agent.sources.r1.filegroups.f1=/home/tail_test_dir/test.txt
    agent.sources.r1.maxBackoffSleep=1000

    #connect to another box using avro and send the data
    agent.sinks.c1.type=avro
    agent.sinks.c1.hostname=10.10.10.4
    agent.sinks.c1.port=4545
```

Configuration on server 2:

```
    #configure the agent
    agent.sources=r1
    agent.channels=k1
    agent.sinks=c1

    #using memory channel to hold up to 1000 events
    agent.channels.k1.type=memory
    agent.channels.k1.capacity=1000
    agent.channels.k1.transactionCapacity=100

    #connect source, channel, sink
    agent.sources.r1.channels=k1
    agent.sinks.c1.channel=k1

    #here source is listening at the specified port using AVRO for data
    agent.sources.r1.type=avro
    agent.sources.r1.bind=0.0.0.0
    agent.sources.r1.port=4545

    #use file_roll and write file at specified directory
    agent.sinks.c1.type=file_roll
    agent.sinks.c1.sink.directory=/home/Flume_dump
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set position json file. Then the source check the position and write only new added lines to sink.
ex) agent.sources.s1.positionFile = /var/log/flume/tail_position.json